# concatenate without losing thousands separator

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I have a report that brings total sales and total probability sale.
The request was that this be shown in one table as `"R"{totalamount}"` `(R"{totprobamount")"`.

So i added this together in a variable with the variable expression being

```
"R" + $F{Totalt} +" (R" + $F{Totalp} +")"
```

but by doing this the Thousands separator does not show anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you can add a field for each value you wouldn't do this with String concatenation but by using patterns on text field. add for each field in the properties panel a patter such as `R #,##0.00`.
- if it has to be in a single field you'd need to add an expression to actually format the numbers in the desired way such as for example:  `"R" + new DecimalFormat("#,##.00").format($F{Totalt}) + " (R" + new DecimalFormat("#,##.00").format($F{Totalp}) + ")"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FORMAT function to have thousand separator.

```
 FORMAT({totalamount} +{totprobamount},2)
```

This column become String column so you have to add this column separately , you cant use same column for integer value. Where 2 is for up to 2 decimal value.

Comment: What is "R", if its a integer column , you can add this also.